# RSA encryption in Python vs Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a small string using Python and Ruby. I've written code in both these languages that should do exactly the same thing:

In Python:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import asn1
from Crypto import Random
import sys, time, signal, socket, requests, re, base64

pubkey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

foobar = "foobar"

pubkey_int = long(pubkey,16)
pub_exp = 65537L
pubkey_obj = RSA.construct((pubkey_int, pub_exp))
encypted_data =  pubkey_obj.encrypt(foobar, pub_exp)
encypted_data_b64 = base64.b64encode(encypted_data[0])

print encypted_data_b64
```

In Ruby:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

pubkey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

foobar = "foobar"

asn1_sequence = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence.new(
  [
    OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer.new("0x#{pubkey}".to_i(16)),
    OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer.new("0x10001".to_i(16))
  ]
)

public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(asn1_sequence)
data = Base64.encode64(public_key.public_encrypt(foobar))
puts data
```

Both these scripts are trying to encrypt the string `foobar` using the same public key. I expected both of them to output the same results each time, however this is not the case. Furthermore, every time the Ruby Script is executed, it outputs a different result.

Can someone help me identify the difference between these two scripts that is responsible for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this issue by reading the documentation for `Class _RSAobj` (https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt)

> Attention: this function performs the plain, primitive RSA encryption
>   (textbook). In real applications, you always need to use proper
>   cryptographic padding, and you should not directly encrypt data with
>   this method. Failure to do so may lead to security vulnerabilities. It
>   is recommended to use modules Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP or
>   Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5 instead.

Looks like cryptographic padding is not used by default in the RSA module for Python, hence the difference.

Modified Python Script:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
import sys, time, signal, socket, requests, re, base64

pubkey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

foobar = "foobar"

pubkey_int = long(pubkey,16)
pub_exp = 65537L
pubkey_obj = RSA.construct((pubkey_int, pub_exp))
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(pubkey_obj)
encypted_data = cipher.encrypt(foobar)
encypted_data_b64 = base64.b64encode(encypted_data)

print encypted_data_b64
```

Comment: just a quick question, so now you have both script that generates the same result and this result is different each time you run the script ?

Comment: @Darkos its different each time for both Scripts, which is the expected results. I will post the modified python script.